# Does the service broker activation procedure need to be in a transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm setting up service broker to do some asynchronous jobs.  The procedure I have to receive messages calls another stored procedure that does a lot of work and the fact that I'm in a transaction is causing some locking issues.  The example, i've patterned this off of came from https://sqlperformance.com/2014/03/sql-performance/configuring-service-broker but I'm wondering if it is a bad idea to remove the transactions from the procedure that is processing the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an explicit transaction, but understand that if you remove it that once the `RECEIVE` statement happens, the message is removed from the queue forever.

Contrast that with the case where you use a transaction. If the activation procedure aborts after the `RECEIVE` but before the transaction that contains it is finished, the message is put back at the top of the queue.

Of course, you have to be careful about poison messages, but at least you're not dropping messages on the floor.

Comment: Thanks for that, that helps. After reading a bit more last night, I think what I'm really after to combat my deadlocking issues is to set the MAX_QUEUE_READERS to 1 so it won't fire off another session of the procedure until the current session is done.

Comment: Sure. There are a lot of ways to go here. How many messages are you receiving from the queue at once? Are you sending a lot of messages on the same conversation handle? What are the resources involved in the deadlock?